# New system has Resolution & lower part of Text getting chopped

Tags: multiple-monitors

Just bought a new Dell 3660 workstation with Following specs.
Two NVIDIA T-600 Cards each with 4miniDP ports to run 8 Monitors ( 24 inch each 1920x1200 resolution)
Windows-11 Pro.
Intel i-7 12700 CPU

Since there are 8 Monitors, I have to sit at least 4 feet away so I can see all 8 monitors & be able to read text from them.

(1) So I increased the text size to Full in Win-11 settings.
But if I do that then text gets clipped of any file or folder names in Windows explorer.It does not get clipped in the left side pane.
So the only way I can read the text is to reduce the text size to only 20%. Any increase to more than 20% will cut the text in half.There is no way I can read that text. This problem occurs in Windows explorer file & folder names. Right now I have enlarged it to 100% but I don't have any problem with text in this post or most websites pages.
I have been using Win-7 with 12 Monitors for 10 years without this problem. So is this Win-11 problem or something else & how do I resolve this issue.

(2) One of the 8 monitor has resolution problem meaning everything including text size is very large just in that one monitor. If I connect the same monitor with my old system there is no problem which rules out any problem with monitor itself. So what is the problem & how do I resolve it.

Thank You

Comment: You should consider sharing a Screen Shot with your Issue

Comment: Without Details , nobody can "guess" at the Solution !